# Creating An Array From jQuery Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have the table:

```
 <table id="mastermind_table_one">
   <tr id="one">
     <td id='first'>First</td>
     <td id='second'>Second</td>
     <td id='third'>Third</td>
     <td id='forth'>Forth</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

How would I go about creating an array that contains each td?

I was hoping to get something like:

```
var array = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Forth"]
```

Comment: `var array = $('#one td').map(function(){ return $.trim($(this).text()); }).get()`.

Comment: Thank you all! I just tried this out and it worked. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

```
var array = $("#one td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
}).get();
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- Yeah, I just thought about that -> changed it to target the row ID followed by children of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = [];
$('#one').children().each(function(){
  newArray.push($(this).html());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xufir/1/)

```
var array = [];
$("#one td").text(function(i, txt) { array.push(txt); });
```